# Simplify JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

For my site I wrote a small piece of JavaScript that updates some elements in the browser when a button is clicked but this code seems to be redundant and inefficient. Is there any way to clean this up?

```
$(function () {
    $('#switch').click(function () {
        if ($('#header').text() == 'Sign In') {
            $('#header').text('Sign Up');
            $('#switch').text('Sign In');
            $('#submit').text('Sign Up');
            $('#submit').attr('form', 'sign_up');
        } else {
            $('#header').text('Sign In');
            $('#switch').text('Sign Up');
            $('#submit').text('Sign In');
            $('#submit').attr('form', 'sign_in');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This would be better on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @woz I'm wasn't aware that StackExchange had that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a small improvement: don't query the jQuery objects each time you use them. Instead, store them in variables:

```
var $switch = $('#switch')
var $submit = $('#submit')
etc.
```

Then use those instead of querying for the same objects so many times.

```
$switch.click(function() {
        if ($header.text() == 'Sign In') {
            $header.text('Sign Up');
            $switch.text('Sign In');
            $submit.text('Sign Up');
            etc.
```